# Code not printing stack trace because of ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: exception, handler

I'm debugging a Spring Boot application, but am finding it extremely difficult to do so because my code isn't printing any stack traces:
[image: no stack trace printed for ArrayOOB exception, so I have no idea where it happened]

What in the world is `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, and does it have to do with my issue?

Answer (score 1):

> ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver matches uncaught exceptions against
>   suitable @ExceptionHandler methods on both the handler (controller)
>   and on any controller-advices.

For more details
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc##extending-exceptionhandlerexceptionresolver

I was facing the same issue as you. 
In my case is I use @ControllerAdvice and I did not have the Exception.class handler case.

When I added it, the stacktrace is printed again.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception: {}", e);
    // your handler code.
}
```